# Can we have an explicit representation of inverse of a softmax function?

Tags: classification, multinomial-logit, softmax

As we know, logit is the inverse of logistic function in case of binary classification. Similar to this, I am willing to derive results for multinomial classification, for that I need to get an explicit representation of the inverse of a softmax function. It would be a kind helpful for me, if someone explain the above inverse with relevant characterisations to derive multinomial logistic regression.

Comment: As we know, in logistic regression the learning concept is provided by linear regression involved in the regression step. I am willing to derive similar results for multinomial classification classification using softmax function.

Comment: The softmax function is not invertible. For example, consider that $\operatorname{softmax}([c, c, \cdots, c])$ yields the same output for all values of $c$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2786600/invert-the-softmax-function and my comment there "Usually they normalize the xi to sum to zero, in which case the inverse softmax would be log(x)-mean(log(x)). Or they code the first xi to be zero, in which case the inverse softmax would be log(x)-log(x[[1]])."